# The profession of the judge [+examples]

Tags: single-word-requests

Which noun is used to denote the occupation (or profession?) of a judge? I thought it was "judgement", but I looked at the definitions of "judg(e)ment" in several dictionaries and couldn't find it anywhere...

Late edit: I've been asked to add sample sentence, so here are two examples:

> 1. [*Judging / The administration of justice*] has always been a revered high-status occupation.
> 2. These procedural reforms were aimed at streamlining [*the administration of justice / adjudication*].

Comment: *Magistracy*. Unless you're a fan of *Beyond the Fringe*--"I never had the Latin for the *judging*".

Comment: A magistrate is a certain type of Judge, but I think the noun is too restrictive for the more general sense sought here. For instance a criminal judge in the High Court, in England, is not part of the magistracy. The profession of a Judge is Judge, like the profession of a policeman, is policeman.

Comment: While "magistracy" is the office of a judge, his work or function can be described as "administration of justice." "judg(e)ment" is the resolution or decree the judge issues after hearing a case.

Comment: Are you looking for a word for what the judge *does*, or a collective noun for judges, or...? If you add a sample sentence where the word would be used, you'll get more precise answers. (Also, a sample sentence is technically required for a single-word-request question.)

Comment: In a general sense, the role performed by a judge is "presiding", their duty is to adjudicate and enforce the operation of the court, their title depends on many factors, their profession is generally their title... other comments are right though, you need to provide context if you want this answered accurately.

Comment: I edited the original question to add sample sentences, as I've been asked to do. Sorry for having omitted it earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Adjudication or judging.

> To [adjudicate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adjudicate): Make a formal judgement on a disputed matter.

(Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: There is also the related occupational noun: adjudicator. See also its synonyms: judge, arbiter and arbitrator.

Answer (score 2):

The profession of a judge is Judge, like the profession of a policeman, is Policeman.

There are various titles for the different judicial offices, in different English speaking parts of the world: e.g. in England and Wales:-

> In the Courts of England and Wales, Supreme Court, judges are called
>   **Justices of the Supreme Court**...
>
> Judges of the Court of Appeal, also called **Lords Justice of Appeal**,
>   are referred to as "Lord Justice N" or "Lady Justice N."...
>
> **Lay magistrates** are sometimes still addressed as "Your Worship"

and, in the US:

> In many states throughout the United States, a judge is addressed as
>   "Your Honor" or "Judge" when presiding over the court. "Judge" may be
>   more commonly used by attorneys and staff...
>   The judges of the Supreme Court of the United States, and the judges
>   of the supreme courts of several US states and other countries are
>   called **"justices**". Justices of the Supreme Court of the United States
>   and Justices of other courts are addressed as "Justice (name)." The
>   Chief Justice of the United States is formally addressed as "Mr. Chief
>   Justice" but also may be identified and addressed as "Chief Justice
>   (name)".
>
> The justices of the supreme courts usually hold higher offices than
>   any other judges in a jurisdiction, including a justice of the peace,
>   a judge who holds police court in some jurisdictions and who may also
>   try small claims and misdemeanors...
>
> New York judges who deal with guardianships, trusts and estates are
>   uniquely known as "**surrogates.**"
>
> A senior judge, in US practice, is a retired judge who handles
>   selected cases for a governmental entity while in retirement, on a
>   part-time basis.
>
> Subordinate or inferior jurisdiction judges in US legal practice are
>   sometimes called **magistrates**, although in the federal court of the
>   United States, they are called **magistrate judges**. Subordinate judges
>   in US legal practice who are appointed on a case-by-case basis,
>   particularly in cases where a great deal of detailed and tedious
>   evidence must be reviewed, are often called **"masters" or "special
>   masters"** and have authority in a particular case often determined on a
>   case by case basis.
>
> Judges of courts of specialized jurisdiction (such as bankruptcy
>   courts or juvenile courts) were sometimes known officially as
>   "**referees,**" but the use of this title is in decline. Judges sitting in
>   courts of equity in common law systems (such as judges in the equity
>   courts of Delaware) are called "**chancellors.**"
>
> Individuals with judicial responsibilities who report to an executive
>   branch official, rather than being a part of the judiciary, are often
>   called "**administrative law judges**" in US practice. They were
>   previously known as hearing examiners...
>
> Judges who derive their authority from a contractual agreement of the
>   parties to a dispute, rather than a governmental body are called
>   **arbitrators**. They typically do not receive the honorific forms of
>   address nor do they bear the symbolic trappings of a publicly
>   appointed judge. However, it is now common for many retired judges to
>   serve as arbitrators, and they will often write their names as if they
>   were still judges, with the parenthetical "(Ret.)" for "Retired."
>
> ...the United States legal system (like most
>   Anglo-American legal systems) makes a clear distinction between
>   professional judges and laypeople involved in deciding a case who are
>   jurors who are part of a jury... Non-lawyer judges in the United
>   States are often elected, and are typically either justices of the
>   peace or part-time judges in rural limited jurisdiction courts. A
>   **non-lawyer judge** typically has the same rights and responsibilities as
>   a lawyer who is a judge holding the same office and is addressed in
>   the same manner.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge#Titles_and_forms_of_address)

But for a catch all term for the profession, Judge works just fine.

Comment: Isn't the profession of the police "law enforcement"?

Comment: -1 Does not address the question . Also policemen do ***policing***.

Comment: @DanBron Police is a profession of itself (http://www.policeprofessional.com/) Police enforce the law for sure, but it is common place to refer to their profession of policing, as being a 'policeman' or 'policewoman in the UK, to be more politically correct you could refer to the profession of police officer, but they are all perfectly fine words to describe the profession of a police person.- e.g. http://www.criminaljusticeusa.com/police-officer/ // lol Spencer, lol is all I can really say to your comment.

Comment: I believe the OP was looking for the word describing the execution of his/her duties. Clearly, 'judge' is the name of the profession.

Comment: @BrianJ "Which noun is used to denote the occupation (or profession?) of a judge?"

Comment: Judge is the profession. I think the OP chose the wrong word in saying "profession " or "occupation ". Seems to me he means the activity associated with the profession.

Answer (score 0):

As an engineer, I am part of *the engineering profession*. The closest equivalent I can think of for a judge is that he is part of ***the [judiciary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/judiciary)***:

> 1. the judicial branch of government.
> 2. the system of courts of justice in a country.
> 3. judges collectively.
>
> **Examples**:
>
> *Like Obama, FDR was skeptical of social reform through the judiciary.*
>
> *I believe the judiciary is impartial and independent, and has been for a long time.*

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>